# Cocoa-bindings, delaying commits of editing until user clicks 'OK'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I have an editing window with several fields, all bound to the 'content' controller key of an NSObjectController, which is in turn bound to the 'selection' controller key of an NSArrayController. I also have an NSTableView, bound to the same NSArrayController, along with its selection.

In my editing window, as soon as the user leaves a textfield, the value is propagated back to the NSTableView. How do I stop the value being committed until the user clicks 'OK' in the editing window?

Comment: I tried to create a new ManagedObjectContext for the editing window, but changes are still immediately reflected even without calling [context save]. I don't know if this is a good approach or not. I'm still binding to the selection of the main ManagedObjectContext, this may make this not work as I intend. Is it possible to copy the selection from one context to another, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temporary `NSMutableDictionary` object to store the values in the editing window, and then when the user clicks 'OK' instantiate an object using the dictionary's values: i.e.:

```
NSManagedObject* obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject"                                             
                        inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];

[obj setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:tempObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a transient value in the editing window. then, when the user clicks 'OK' actually assign the value.

Comment: Do you mean... bind to a wrapper for `[obj value]` like `[obj valueTransient]`, then in the method when the user clicks OK, go through and do '[obj setValue: [objValueTransient]]`? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, i just meant use a completely separate object until the user hits OK